# jQuery Chain & Collect

Tags: jquery, promise, chaining

Imagine that I am chaining three asynchronous calls, as in:

```
$.when(first()).then(second()).then(third())
```

`first()`, `second()`, and `third()` all return Deferred objects.

At the end of the chain, I'd like to collect everything that was resolved. In my mind, I imagine:

```
$.when(first()).then(second()).then(third()).finally(
  function(first,second,third){
    //Do stuff with the three returns here
  }
);
```

But is there a syntax for doing such a thing? Or how might it be done?

Or, put another way, a syntax like `$.when(first(),second(),third())` which assures sequential, non-overlapping execution of `first()`, `second()`, and `third()` would be ideal.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*each have a call to `resolve()` inside of them*"? Do they return a promise? Do they resolve some other deferred? You might show us an example code.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you have to resort to the pyramid of doom (or, of callbacks):

```
first().then(function(firstResult) {
    second(firstResult).then(function(secondResult) {
        third(secondResult).then(function(thirdResult) {
            // now you have all three results available in scope
        });
    });
});
```

If you wanted to flatten that, I can only see

```
var firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult;
$.when(first()).done(function(r) { firstResult = r; })
 .then(second).done(function(r) { secondResult = r; })
 .then(third).done(function(r) { thirdResult = r; })
 .finally(function() {
     // use the three results here
 });
```

or some kind of

```
first().then(function(r) { return [r]; })
.then(function(a) {
    return second(a[0]).then(function(r) { a.push(r); return a; });
}).then(function(a) {
    return third(a[1]).then(function(r) { a.push(r); return a; });
}).finally(function(a) {
    use a[0], a[1] and a[2] here
});
```

Maybe a helper function, with the `arguments` object instead of the array, can simplify that:

```
function unfoldLast(fn) {
    return function() {
         var args = arguments,
             l = args.length,
             last = arguments[l-1];
         return fn(last).then(function(r) {
             var d = $.Deferred();
             args[l] = r;
             d.resolve.apply(d, args);
             return d;
         });
    };
}
first().then(unfoldLast(second)).then(unfoldLast(third))
 .done(function(firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult) {
     // use the arguments!
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the second solution right now. But, verily, it is bothersome!

Comment: Do the functions actually rely on each other? If not, you might be interested in the [`series` function of the `async` library](https://github.com/caolan/async#series).

Comment: No, they don't rely on each other. But I do need them to run sequentially without overlapping and have the results collected at the end.